# What is the difference between Any and Unit?

Tags: scala

What is the difference between `Any` and `Unit` in Scala ?
I know both are datatypes, but what is the difference ?

Comment: Ham... like thousands of them. Have you read something basic about the [**Scala Type Hierarchy**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html)?  `Any` is the top type, it is the super type of all other types _(meaning every other type is a subtype of it)_. While `Unit` is just an special type with only one habitant _(`()` alo know as the Unit)_. Which is used to represent the return type of functions that only perform side effects, like `println`. - On what of that do you see them similar?

Comment: Any is similar to Object in java, Unit is similar to Void

Answer (score 3):

`Unit` is kind of like Java's `void`, except it has an actual value (`()` is the only value of type `Unit`).

`Any` is the parent type of every other type. `()` is an instance of `Any`. `1` is an instance of `Any`. `"Hello"` is an instance of `Any`.

`Any` has two direct sub-types; `AnyVal` (which includes types that Java would consider "primitives" like `Int` and `Boolean`), and `AnyRef` (like `java.lang.Object`).

Answer (score 2):

`Any` represents an object of any type, roughly the same as `void *` in C/C++.

`Unit` represents no object, roughly the same as `void` in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

Neither carries much semantic meaning in the following sense:

- if we have a value of type `Any` we do not really know what kind of value it is unless we cast it at runtime
- if we have a value of `Unit` we know a side-effect was executed, but we do not really know much about the kind of side-effect it was.

Ideally, we want to narrow down the meaning of the program as much as possible, thus we try to minimise the usage of `Any` and `Unit`, whilst maximising the usage of semantically richer types.

As a side-note, `Any` is the root of the Scala class hierarchy, which means even `Unit` is a subtype of `Any`, for example, the following is valid: `val a: Any = ()`.